# Update query with a third table involved in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I'm fairly new to SQL coding and am still learning some of the intricacies.
I've researched and couldn't find an example that related to what I'm trying (maybe I'm missing the right keywords).

I have three tables in SQL Server 2016 (an employee table - E1, an imported table with employee data - ED1 and a department table - D1)...pertinent structure for this question is:

E1 in DB1 contains columns

```
U_SysID - Identity,  
UserID - VARCHAR,  
FirstName - VARCHAR,  
LastName - VARCHAR,  
DepartmentID - VARCHAR
```

ED1 in DB2 with schema of dbo contains columns

```
UserID - VARCHAR,   
FirstName - VARCHAR,  
LastName - VARCHAR,  
DepartmentName - VARCHAR
```

D1 in DB1 contains columns

```
DepartmentID - Identity and  
DepartmentName - VARCHAR
```

Code I came up with to try to accomplish this is:

```
USE DB1
GO

UPDATE E1 
SET DepartmentID = (SELECT DepartmentID 
                    FROM D1
                    WHERE E1.UserID IN (SELECT UserID 
                                        FROM DB2.dbo.ED1) 
                      AND D1.DepartmentName IN (SELECT DepartmentName 
                                                FROM ED1) 
                      AND E1.UserID = DB2.dbo.ED1.UserID)
```

My problem is the last line.  The "DB2.dbo.ED1.UserID" produces a multi-part identifier could not be bound message.  There are no typos and there is no problem with the use of that database reference in the select statement above it, but if I remove the last line then I get the message that the sub query returned more than 1 value.

Any time spent reading this and providing suggestions is greatly appreciated.

I also apologize in advance if I didn't formulate this post correctly.

Comment: You should be using joins instead of all those subqueries. And be careful because as you have this written you may get more than 1 value returned.

Comment: Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you require. However, you should also check for missing or misspelled DepartmentNames, Missing Users, etc.

```
USE DB1
GO

UPDATE E1
SET DepartmentID = D1.DepartmentID
FROM E1 
INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.ED1 ED1
    ON E1.UserID = ED1.UserID
INNER JOIN D1
    ON ED1.DepartmentName = D1.DepartmentName
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give this a try.